# Django filter by hour

Tags: python, django

I've found that link: http://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/8424/time_filters.diff and changed my django 1.2 files by adding taht what you can see there.
But now, when I'm trying to  write Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__hour = x) - the result is following error:

> Field has invalid lookup: hour

What should I do else, to make it work?

(sorry for my english)

Comment: I am not quite sure if this patch is meant to be working with 1.2.

Answer (score 7):

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__hour = x)
```

is not supported as of django 1.2 - only year, month, day, week_day.

Use something like this:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__regex = '08:00')
```

or

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__contains = '08:00')
```

which will give you all Entry objects with the hour (over all years).

Answer (score 3):

This is supported natively by Django, using the [`hour` field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#hour):

```py
Event.objects.filter(timestamp__hour=23)
Event.objects.filter(time__hour=5)
Event.objects.filter(timestamp__hour__gte=12)
```

This is equivalent to using SQL `EXTRACT('hour' FROM timestamp)`.

When `USE_TZ` is True, datetime fields are converted to the current time zone before filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Django 1.7 added support for custom lookups and transforms. A hour transform is implemented as follows on PostgreSQL:

```
class HourExtract(models.Transform):
    lookup_name = 'hour'
    output_type = models.IntegerField()

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs_sql, lhs_params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        return "EXTRACT(hour FROM %s)" % lhs_sql, lhs_params

models.DateTimeField.register_lookup(HourExtract)
```

Now you can do .filter(pub_date__hour__lte=x) and other similar queries on the hour value.

Comment: When I do that and try to filter using MyModel.objects.filter(date__hour=8), django says that it expects a strnig or buffer as if the date__hour was expected as a datetime and not as an integer

Answer (score 1):

Probably better of using a raw SQL query like:

```
Whatever.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIME(pub_date) LIKE '%%08:30%%' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you defined `pub_date` as a `DateField`, but it must be a `DateTimeField`? Can you include in the question your model definition code?