# Django lookups for specific hour and minutes

Tags: django

As far as I know, django does have lookups only for year, month and day. I am looking for something is equivalent to this code to get specific hour range for every Sunday for example: Every Sunday 10:50-12:35:

```
 Entry.objects.filter(Record_Date__week_day=1,)
    Record_Date__hour__gte=10)
    Record_Date__hour__lte=12)
    Record_Date__minute__gte=50)
    Record_Date__minute__lte=35)
```

Do you have any idea for an alternative to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django filter by hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984751/django-filter-by-hour)

Answer (score 0):

`__hour` and `__minute` do not exist in django, yet your code would not be valid as `11:00` would be excluded.

I guess you will have to deal with [__regex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex) or [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also just make two datetime objects, and `filter(Record_Date__gte=start_datetime, Record_Date__lte=end_datetime)`.

It is confusing that Django doesn't choke, is Record_Date a ForeignKey to a model that has fields "minute", "hour" and "week_day" ?